# How do I specify different date ranges for CustomBusinessDays holidays in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetimeoffset

I have a data set that I have to group according to lecture days and non-lecture days. The best way I can think of to do this, would be to use `CustomBusinessDay` and specify holiday (non-lecture day) periods. (Another alternative would be to use `bdate_range` and remove the list holiday dates from it, but I haven't had much luck doing so either.)

However, when I pass my list of holidays in `CustomBusinessDay`, I get the following error:

> TypeError: dt must be datestring, datetime or datetime64

It seems that I cannot use a list of `DatetimeIndex` objects for `holidays`. Is there better way to do this? My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
nolectures=[pd.date_range(start='2015-03-28',end='2015-04-12'),  '2015-05-01', pd.date_range(start='2015-11-09',end='2015-12-31'),]
calendar=CustomBusinessDay(holidays=nolectures)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nolectures` is a heterogenous list of DatetimeIndexes and strings:

```
nolectures=[pd.date_range(start='2015-03-28',end='2015-04-12'),  '2015-05-01', pd.date_range(start='2015-11-09',end='2015-12-31'),]
```

You need `nolectures` to be an array-like of dates:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay

nolectures = pd.date_range(start='2015-03-28',end='2015-04-12').union_many(
    [['2015-05-01'], pd.date_range(start='2015-11-09',end='2015-12-31')])
calendar = CustomBusinessDay(holidays=nolectures)
print(calendar.holidays)
```